# Hands On Project 7-2 Day of Week box below Select a date

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a problem displaying the project correctly, it seems that the second box is located below the first box when it should be appearing to the right side of the box. I am not sure if this is a problem with HTML or with CSS, because I have tried looking at the ID day and it doesn't seem to have anything wrong. But I could be making a mistake there. If anyone has a solution to this it would be much appreciated, please let me know. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
 <title>Hands-on Project 7-2</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
 <script src="modernizr.custom.05819.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <header>
  <h1>
     Hands-on Project 7-2
  </h1>
  </header>

   <article>
  <h2>Day of the Week Lookup</h2>
  <form>
      <fieldset>
        <label for="dateSelected">
          Select a date
        </label>
        <input type="date" id="dateSelected" />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="button">
        <button type="button" id="determineDay">Find day</button>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
         <p>Day of the Week</p>
        <p id="day"></p>
      </fieldset>
 </form>
   </article>
    <script>
   var selection = document.getElementById("dateSelected");

   var result = document.getElementById("day");

   var allDaysofWeek = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

   var selectedDate;

   var dayOfWeekNumber;

   var dayOfWeekName;

   function lookUpDay () {

       selectedDate = new Date(selection.value);

       selectedDate.setUTCHours(12);

       dayOfWeekNumber = selectedDate.getUTCDay();

       dayOfWeekName = allDaysofWeek[dayOfWeekNumber];

       result.innerHTML = dayOfWeekName;
      }

    // add event listener to Find day button and clear form

    function createEventListener () {

        var submitButton = document.getElementById("determineDay");

        if (submitButton.addEventListener) {
            submitButton.addEventListener("click", lookUpDay, false);
                                            } 

            else if (submitButton.attachEvent) {
                submitButton.attachEvent ("onclick", lookUpDay);    
            }

        document.getElementById("dateSelected").value = "";
        // clear last starting value on reload

        document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = "";
        // clear previous results on reload
    }

    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("load", createEventListener, false);
                                }
    else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent ("onload", createEventListener);}


   </script>
   </body>
   </html>



 /* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
  * {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 /* reset rules */
 html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
 h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
 a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
 del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
 small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
 b, u, i, center,
 dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
 fieldset, form, label, legend,
 table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
 article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
 figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
 menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
 time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
 }

 /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
 article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
 footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
  }

 body {
  line-height: 1;
   max-width: 600px;
   background: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
   -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 0px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1),
                   0px 10px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1),
                   -10px 0px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow:    10px 0px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1),
                   0px 10px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1),
                   -10px 0px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
   box-shadow:         10px 0px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1),
                   0px 10px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1),
                   -10px 0px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
   }

   ol, ul {
   list-style: none;
    }

   /* page header */
  header {
   background: #04819E;
   width: 100%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 48px;
    text-align: center;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   }

/* main content */
 article {
  text-align: center;
  background: ivory;
  padding: 20px;
 }

 article h2 {
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 24px;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  /* form */

 form {
   padding: 10px;
   height: 145px;
   }

fieldset {
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   position: relative;
   padding: 2.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
   background: #e3d5ba;
   float: left;
    width: 40%;
   height: 125px;
   }

 fieldset.button {
   width: 20%;
 }

input {
  font-size: 1.1em;
   width: 4em;
  clear: left;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
  text-align: center;
 }

input:focus {
  background: #e3d5ba;
  }

 label {
   display: block;
  }

 input, label, button, form p {
  margin: 5px 10px;
  }

 p {
   clear: left;
   }

 #dateSelected {
   width: 180px;
   }

 #day {
   width: 120px;
   font-size: 1.1em;
   height: 1.6em;
   background: white;
   padding: 0.2em;
  margin: 10px auto;
    border: 1px solid rgb(164,164,164);
}
```

Comment: You don't have any CSS. Is what you provided a [mcve] that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Verifiable problem, it appears on all browsers

Comment: Do you have CSS in styles.css?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `display: flex` on the `form` and that will put the `fieldset`s in a row that you can control with flex layout properties. Then you can move the backgrounds, paddings and margins to the `form` instead of having to set them individually on the `fieldset`s

```css
 /* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
 
 * {
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 /* reset rules */
 
 html,
 body,
 div,
 span,
 applet,
 object,
 iframe,
 h1,
 h2,
 h3,
 h4,
 h5,
 h6,
 p,
 blockquote,
 pre,
 a,
 abbr,
 acronym,
 address,
 big,
 cite,
 code,
 del,
 dfn,
 em,
 img,
 ins,
 kbd,
 q,
 s,
 samp,
 small,
 strike,
 strong,
 sub,
 sup,
 tt,
 var,
 b,
 u,
 i,
 center,
 dl,
 dt,
 dd,
 ol,
 ul,
 li,
 fieldset,
 form,
 label,
 legend,
 table,
 caption,
 tbody,
 tfoot,
 thead,
 tr,
 th,
 td,
 article,
 aside,
 canvas,
 details,
 embed,
 figure,
 figcaption,
 footer,
 header,
 hgroup,
 menu,
 nav,
 output,
 ruby,
 section,
 summary,
 time,
 mark,
 audio,
 video {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
   font-size: 100%;
   font: inherit;
   vertical-align: baseline;
 }
 /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
 
 article,
 aside,
 details,
 figcaption,
 figure,
 footer,
 header,
 hgroup,
 menu,
 nav,
 section {
   display: block;
 }
 
 body {
   line-height: 1;
   max-width: 600px;
   background: white;
   margin: 0 auto;
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 0px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1), 0px 10px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1), -10px 0px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
   -moz-box-shadow: 10px 0px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1), 0px 10px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1), -10px 0px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
   box-shadow: 10px 0px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1), 0px 10px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1), -10px 0px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
 }
 
 ol,
 ul {
   list-style: none;
 }
 /* page header */
 
 header {
   background: #04819E;
   width: 100%;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-size: 48px;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 }
 /* main content */
 
 article {
   text-align: center;
   background: ivory;
   padding: 20px;
 }
 
 article h2 {
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 24px;
   padding: 10px;
 }
 /* form */
 
 form {
   padding: 10px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   background: #e3d5ba;
   padding: 2.5em 0 1em;
 }
 
 fieldset {
   position: relative;
   width: 40%;
 }
 
 fieldset.button {
   width: 20%;
 }
 
 input {
   font-size: 1.1em;
   width: 4em;
   clear: left;
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   text-align: center;
 }
 
 input:focus {
   background: #e3d5ba;
 }
 
 label {
   display: block;
 }
 
 input,
 label,
 button,
 form p {
   margin: 5px 10px;
 }
 
 p {
   clear: left;
 }
 
 #dateSelected {
   width: 180px;
 }
 
 #day {
   width: 120px;
   font-size: 1.1em;
   height: 1.6em;
   background: white;
   padding: 0.2em;
   margin: 10px auto;
   border: 1px solid rgb(164, 164, 164);
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
  <title>Hands-on Project 7-2</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <script src="modernizr.custom.05819.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>
     Hands-on Project 7-2
  </h1>
  </header>

  <article>
    <h2>Day of the Week Lookup</h2>
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <label for="dateSelected">
          Select a date
        </label>
        <input type="date" id="dateSelected" />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="button">
        <button type="button" id="determineDay">Find day</button>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <p>Day of the Week</p>
        <p id="day"></p>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </article>
  <script>
    var selection = document.getElementById("dateSelected");
  
     var result = document.getElementById("day");
  
     var allDaysofWeek = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  
     var selectedDate;
  
     var dayOfWeekNumber;
  
     var dayOfWeekName;
  
     function lookUpDay () {
  
         selectedDate = new Date(selection.value);
  
         selectedDate.setUTCHours(12);
  
         dayOfWeekNumber = selectedDate.getUTCDay();
  
         dayOfWeekName = allDaysofWeek[dayOfWeekNumber];
  
         result.innerHTML = dayOfWeekName;
        }
  
      // add event listener to Find day button and clear form
  
      function createEventListener () {
  
          var submitButton = document.getElementById("determineDay");
  
          if (submitButton.addEventListener) {
              submitButton.addEventListener("click", lookUpDay, false);
                                              } 
  
              else if (submitButton.attachEvent) {
                  submitButton.attachEvent ("onclick", lookUpDay);    
              }
  
          document.getElementById("dateSelected").value = "";
          // clear last starting value on reload
  
          document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = "";
          // clear previous results on reload
      }
  
      if (window.addEventListener) {
          window.addEventListener("load", createEventListener, false);
                                  }
      else if (window.attachEvent) {
          window.attachEvent ("onload", createEventListener);}
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This cleared up a lot for me :)

Comment: @AnnaMarkiewicz you're welcome. be sure to upvote answers if they help, and accept one once you feel your issue is resolved.